# Facing issue with CometD on tomcat 7.0.71

Tags: tomcat

Getting following error with cometd 3.0.1 with tomcat 7.0.73 with long polling. We haven't seen this issue with tomcat 7.0.50.

From CometD developer

> javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getAsyncContext(ServletRequestWrapper.java:418) 
>   org.cometd.server.transport.AbstractStreamHttpTransport.process(AbstractStreamHttpTransport.java:88)

**This is where CometD resumes a long poll after having suspended it, so 
it is perfectly legal to call getAsyncContext(), which is what Tomcat 
complains about.**

Is there a way to make long polling work with Tomcat?

```
Time: Fri Mar 24 2017 17:46:55 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) Channel: null Reason: Error occured during CometD connect.
Failure Message: {"id":"4","successful":false,"channel":"/meta/connect","failure":{"reason":"error","exception":"Internal Server Error","httpCode":500,"connectionType":"long-polling","transport":{"readyState":4,"withCredentials":true,"responseText":"

HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode (i.e. isAsyncStarted() returns false)
type Exception report

message java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode (i.e. isAsyncStarted() returns false)

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode (i.e. isAsyncStarted() returns false)\n\tcom.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)\n\torg.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)\n\torg.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)\n\torg.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)\n\torg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:317)\n\torg.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.asyncDispatch(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1681)\n\torg.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:616)\n\torg.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)\n\torg.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)\n\tjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\n\tjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\n\torg.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tjava.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n
root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode (i.e. isAsyncStarted() returns false)\n\tcom.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)\n\torg.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)\n\torg.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)\n\torg.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)\n\torg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:317)\n\torg.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.asyncDispatch(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1681)\n\torg.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:616)\n\torg.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)\n\torg.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)\n\tjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\n\tjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\n\torg.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tjava.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: It is illegal to call this method if the current request is not in asynchronous mode (i.e. isAsyncStarted() returns false)\n\torg.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getAsyncContext(Request.java:1740)\n\torg.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getAsyncContext(RequestFacade.java:1047)\n\tjavax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getAsyncContext(ServletRequestWrapper.java:418)\n\torg.cometd.server.transport.AbstractStreamHttpTransport.process(AbstractStreamHttpTransport.java:88)\n\torg.cometd.server.transport.AbstractStreamHttpTransport.handle(AbstractStreamHttpTransport.java:61)\n\torg.cometd.server.CometDServlet.service(CometDServlet.java:103)\n\tjavax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)\n
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.73 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.73

","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"},"message":{"channel":"/meta/connect","connectionType":"long-polling","id":"4","clientId":"a10paginvut3d5yfwc3azxjvpa","ext":{"ack":-1}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cometd-users/92AiWQF5DdU this has already been fixed in https://github.com/cometd/cometd/issues/557 .